# Accessing iOS Safari Web Inspector from Windows Machine

Tags: ios, windows, safari, web-inspector

New iOS 6 Safari comes with Web Inspector feature which allows to connect to it from your desktop Safari via USB cable. It then allows you to debug pages opened in iOS Safari from your desktop. But as far as I seen, this feature curently supported only on Mac Safari, not on Windows? Am I right, or Windows Safari also has the possibility? Or it will become available later maybe?

Comment: See also [iOS6 - removed console log for IPad - how to use web inspector on windows?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12583275/ios6-removed-console-log-for-ipad-how-to-use-web-inspector-on-windows).

Answer (score 44, accepted):

It appears to require Safari 6, which has not been released for Windows. Regarding the unavailability of Safari 6 on Windows, Apple has stated "Safari 6 is available for Mountain Lion and Lion. Safari 5 continues to be available for Windows."

Comment: I'm normally a bit of an Apple fanboy, but this is pretty irritating.

Comment: I'm not much of an Apple fanboy, and this is pretty irritating ;-)

Comment: I guess there will be no 'Real Device Method' web inspecting with iDevices on PC's...

Comment: I never was much of an apple fanbody, but now I hate them.

Comment: I'm in the same shoes. I have an iPad, but no other Apple devices. So I need to buy an Apple desktop or walk down the hackintosh route.

Comment: Although many answers to this question are wildly out of date (the landscape changes rapidly) it is not necessary to run Safari or a Mac to debug iOS safari on windows. There are a handful of third-party and open-source options.

Answer (score 27):

I regularly use `weinre`. It basically runs a webserver that in turn acts as an inspector-enhanced proxy to browse webpages and websites. The inspector can be started by adding a script to your page or running a bookmarklet.

> weinre is a debugger for web pages, like FireBug (for FireFox) and Web Inspector (for WebKit-based browsers), except it's designed to work remotely, and in particular, to allow you debug web pages on a mobile device such as a phone.

To install it, you will need NodeJS and NPM (included with NodeJS). You will also need a WebKit-based browser on the desktop/receiver end (Safari, Google Chrome, or Chromium). It should work on Windows, OSX, and Linux.

- Official page: https://people.apache.org/~pmuellr/weinre/
- Documentation & Getting Started: https://people.apache.org/~pmuellr/weinre/docs/latest/
- NPM Package: https://www.npmjs.com/package/weinre

If you already have NodeJS and NPM installed, you can install and run it with:

```
npm i -g weinre
weinre
# Go to the URL that it outputs for instructions to use it
```

[image: screenshot of developer tools and ios simulator, showing weinre in action]

#### UPDATE:

@EvAlex has pointed out another tool very similar to Weinre called [Vorlon.js](http://vorlonjs.com/). It is pluggable and supports viewing/switching between the inspector of multiple devices simultaneously.

Comment: That's awesome! I easily installed the node package. After that I started two ngrok instances, one of them serving my local development website and the other serving weinre. Then I added the script tag (pointing to the weinre's public ngrok DNS name js include). Then I can view the website on the iPad using the public ngrok address *plus* can debug it from my local Linux or Windows. That really made my day!

Comment: Thanks both for weinre and ngrok. I'm thinking about vorlon.js instead of weinre now.

Comment: Using iOS 10 and Nginx on Windows 10, I couldn't get this working. A waste of several hours. I'm so frustrated with Apple right now.

Comment: Whoa, right as I was giving up, I discovered https://www.undefinednull.com/2015/03/17/remote-debugging-localhost-with-weinre/ Now I seem to have it working. My command in Windows command prompt is `weinre --boundHost 192.168.0.103 --httpPort 8080` and I added this to the top of my webpage: `<script>
        window.WeinreServerURL="http://192.168.0.103:8080";
        </script>
        <script src="http://192.168.0.103:8080/target/target-script-min.js#anonymous"></script>` Then on my iPhone I browsed to http://192.168.0.103. Thanks. Hopefully this will help with debugging JS on iOS.

Comment: Weinre is not a 100% reliable debugging solution. For one, it injects code into the runtime environment, code that may interfere with your application (the one you are trying to debug) where bugs no longer appear. I am sitting here and pulling my hair out where I have an issue with a Web application (displayed in the so-called "web view" through Apache Cordova framework) where as soon as I link the Weinre debugger script, the issue disappears. So I can't debug without Weinre (I don't have a Mac) and I can't debug with it either. Look at Weinre's code and you'll see why.

Comment: Weinre is no longer maintained.

Answer (score 9):

**Setup Vorlon on Windows**

```
npm i -g vorlon
vorlon
```

**Verify Vorlon is Running**

Open a web browser and navigate to http://localhost:1337

**Setup Ngrok**

- Download Ngrok: https://ngrok.com/download
- Unzip it
- Open a command prompt: `Start -> Search -> cmd`
- Navigate to ngrok.exe: `cd <ngrok_path_where_ngrok.exe is stored>/`
- Run it: `ngrok.exe http <port>` e.g. `ngrok.exe http 1337`

Ngrok provides a url e.g. `https://0ad8c32f.ngrok.io -> localhost:1337`

Copy and paste the ngrok url into your webpage.

```
<script src="https://0ad8c32f.ngrok.io/vorlon.js"></script>
```

Navigate to the page under test on your device(s):

```
http://thepageiwanttotest.com/testing123
```

**References**

- Vorlon Reference: http://www.vorlonjs.com/#getting-started
- Ngrok Reference: https://ngrok.com/download

Answer (score 3):

Stumbled upon this blog [which shows how to debug iOS web app on Windows](http://blog.falafel.com/Blogs/josh-eastburn/2014/03/04/ios-web-inspector-on-windows-with-telerik-appbuilder) using a stndalone app by Telerik called AppBuilder. You're supposed to create an account on their platform before using it and it has a 30 day trial.

I've used this on windows 7 64 bit for both vanilla web apps and Phonegap apps both on iPad with iOS 7.1, and it works. You get web development tools very similar to those in Chrome.

Comment: AppBuilder was discontinued in 2016

Answer (score 1):

I have found a great tool called [GapDebug](https://www.genuitec.com/products/gapdebug/)

that's was the right solution for me :)

Comment: Remember to indicate Debug build in Settings on PhoneGap Build website that has your app. GapDebug worked for me too.

Comment: Sad to report that GapDebug was end-of-life'd in 2016.  It only works for old versions of ios (9 or 10 I think) so pretty much not an option anymore.  But that product was fantastic!

Answer (score 0):

After trying to get Weinre installed on my Windows 10 machine which is running IIS and a localhost client and never being able to get it to work, I looked for an alternate solution.

Turns out Safari for Windows was discontinued by Apple but I was able to fine a copy after discovering the following link.  Oh, the Web Inspector in Safari was able to help me find the problem in my application once it was installed.

[https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/68836/where-can-i-download-safari-for-windows](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/94010/221180)

Once Safari was installed, I needed to turn on the developer tools.  This required going into Preferences > Advanced > check "Show Develop menu in menu bar" > (click on page icon next to sprocket icon hover over Develop) Start Debugging in JavaScript.  From here on it felt very much like Chrome...:-)

Answer (score 0):

Use [iOS WebKit debug proxy](https://github.com/google/ios-webkit-debug-proxy#installation)

It allows you to debug directly in Chrome with live preview.

Comment: This is no longer compatible with Chrome and doesn't seem to receive any debugging data

Answer (score 0):

Found this question in 2024 looking for ways to inspect/debug iOS Safari without access to a Mac and discovered most answers are obsolete.

### What Fully Worked

[Inspect](https://inspect.dev/) is a commercial offering with a free trial. Requires iTunes to be installed. Beyond that, very much plug-and-play. After 12 hours alternating between trying (and failing) with various tools and browsing Mac Minis on eBay, this was refreshing.

[Eruda Mobile Console](https://github.com/liriliri/eruda) - Basically add the following [bookmarklet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bookmarklet) to your mobile device:

```
javascript:(function () { var script = document.createElement('script'); script.src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/eruda"; document.body.append(script); script.onload = function () { eruda.init(); } })();
```

Load the site you wish to debug, then select the bookmark from your device. A console will appear. You won't have access to any events that took place before eruda was loaded, also it won't persist across page navigation events. Alternatively, it may be directly embedded in development builds. Also available is [chii](https://github.com/liriliri/chii) a remote debugging tool from the same maintainers.

### What *Might* Work

[Vorlonjs](https://www.vorlonjs.com/) The links in other answers were broken so I assumed it was another abandoned project. This is the correct link. Github Issues/Discussions indicate the [project might be abandoned](https://github.com/MicrosoftDX/Vorlonjs/issues/457). The only response in two years is a recommending eruda/chii.

### What Didn't Work

**Weinre** was deprecated several years ago and after many hours I was not able to get it to work:

> This project is being deprecated. No more work will be done on this project by the Cordova development community. You can continue to use this project and it should work as-is, but issues will not be fixed by the Cordova community.

**iOS Webkit Debug Proxy** does not appear to work anymore. Chrome is nolonger compatible

> In recent versions of Chrome and Safari there're major discrepancies between Chrome Remote Debugging Protocol and Webkit Inspector Protocol, which means that newer versions of Chrome DevTools aren't compatible with Safari.

Firefox support relies on an abandoned plugin, Valance:

> This project is no longer maintained
> Mozilla no longer maintains this project.

And although it could see my device and tabs, it could not receive any debugging data.

**GapDebug** is discontinued

**Telerik AppBuilder** is discontinued and I haven't been able to find its successor in any of their product lines.

Comment: When I asked this question 11.5 years ago I couldn't have guessed that it will still receive new anwers after all these years =)
I see it even has some "Part of Mobile Development Collective" badge now.
And I don't have many stackoverflow questions, most probably less than 10.