# Debugging web app on ipad without Mac

Tags: ipad, debugging, asp.net-mvc-4, web-applications

I'm tasked with fixing a bug on the mobile version of a project I just came on (and still learning my way around it). Its a heavy use 24/7 kinda job, so not keen on the trial and error guess/upload/test style of debugging.The bug is that almost none of the controls, particularly tabs, respond to user "clicks" on the ipad. The app was developed in asp.net MVC4 and I work on windows 7 in vs2012.

We are not a mac shop, but still need to support the Ipad and phone.

This is probably a simple question: but my searching keeps taking me 
here: [iOS6 - removed console log for IPad - how to use web inspector on windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12583275/ios6-removed-console-log-for-ipad-how-to-use-web-inspector-on-windows)
and here: [Accessing iOS Safari Web Inspector from Windows Machine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12556895/accessing-ios-safari-web-inspector-from-windows-machine).

I need a way to gather actually diagnostics, like what would be available in web inspector, without having to acquire a mac.

Comment: Not only do you have to get a iPad, but now you need a Mac to connect the iPad too! No, I'm not buying that junk (no matter how good-looking and well presented it is, and no matter how well it runs) to be able to sit and debug buggy junk so that idiots who buy junk can run the web app on their junk too... No.
That is my opinion.
Yes, I'm outspoken.
Hoping to find a solution as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `weinre`. It runs a webserver that that can repond to a bookmarklet or `<script>` to run a remote inspector.

> weinre is a debugger for web pages, like FireBug (for FireFox) and Web Inspector (for WebKit-based browsers), except it's designed to work remotely, and in particular, to allow you debug web pages on a mobile device such as a phone.

Get NodeJS, NPM, and a webkit-based desktop browser to run it.

- Homepage: [https://people.apache.org/~pmuellr/weinre/](https://people.apache.org/%7Epmuellr/weinre/)
- Docs: [https://people.apache.org/~pmuellr/weinre/docs/latest/](https://people.apache.org/%7Epmuellr/weinre/docs/latest/)

---

To install with yarn:

```
yarn add --dev weinre
```

then because it's no longer maintained, you may get `TypeError: mime.lookup is not a function` when you try to use it, then you have to edit `node_modules/connect/lib/middleware/static.js` and change `require('mime')` to `require('mime-types')` on line 21 ([thanks](https://www.jianshu.com/p/b29f77040d84)). Then start with

```
yarn run weinre
```

If you now open the url showed there, you'll see the bookmarklet you can use etc. (Note: If using this from other computers, you may have to open local firewall ports, and if debugging a https site you may have to add a reverse proxy with cors headers.)