# iOS Web Inspector vs. Telerik AppBuilder comparison

Tags: ios, iphone, safari-web-inspector, telerik-appbuilder

We are building GWT Web Application mainly focused on iOS + Safari platform. I need to debug and profile the application directly on the device. We are working only on Windows computers.

As mentioned e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12556895/accessing-ios-safari-web-inspector-from-windows-machine), one cannot use iOS Web Inspector built in in Safari, since the newest version of Safari is not available for Windows.

So we started to use alternative tool Telerik AppBuilder to do it, as suggested e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20408110/debug-ipad-safari-with-a-pc/24175132#24175132). I am quite happy with it and it is getting more and more powerful.

However I would like to see comparison of those two tools by someone, who has experience with both of them. I am considering, whenever to invest into Mac computer to be able to use Web Inspector. Are there any features or advantages in Web Inspector, which Telerik does not have?

Comment: You can actually use the web inspector on an iOS device with Telerik AppBuilder. [Docs here](http://docs.telerik.com/platform/appbuilder/debugging-your-code/debugging-on-device/debug-on-ios-device).

Comment: Rob, thanks for the comment. I think this is what I am doing now. I use Telerik AppBuilder to see, what is going on the iOS device, which needs to have  Web Inspector enabled. My question is more about Web Inspector endpoint debugger, which runs on Mac computer in Safari browser. Does it provide some extra features than Telerik? Worth it to invest into Mac computer to be able to use Web Inspector there?

Comment: If you are using GWT I suggest you take a look at Codename One which provides native Java support for mobile devices

Comment: Thanks for suggestion, Shai. We already have the project done with Vaadin + GWT. I use Telerik only for debugging purposes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on my further experience, Telerik is good enough to do all debugging we need. And since it is based on same API as debugger in Safari, it has about same features. It is not as good as Safari debugger, but close enough. Investment into Mac computer just for debugging features is not worth the advantages.