# Are there any developer tools for Chrome for iPad

Tags: ipad, google-chrome, ios6

I've just downloaded Google Chrome for iPad, I'm aware that it uses the webkit engine same as Safari, and so should be able to fix most of my issues using the Safari Dev Tools which already exist.

The problem is that my site hangs in Chrome but not in Safari - so:

**How do I debug my site using Chrome for iPad?**

The version number I have is (21.0.1180.82)

Comment: Here is a nice trick: https://www.webkit.org/blog/1620/webkit-remote-debugging/ However, there is no real native debugging tool for the iPad, yet...

Comment: The question is answered here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11262236/ios-remote-debugging