# Remote Javascript Debugging with Weinre (Web Inspector Remote)

Tags: debugging, mobile, weinre

Can we remotely debug more three mobiles parallely using weinre?

Answer (score 1):

Why not? Just select a device you want to debug:

[image]

See great set of instructions on how to setup weinre: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22047495/775359