# Remote debugging Chrome for iOS

Tags: javascript, ios, macos, webview, safari

I'm trying to debug an error on Chrome for iPad. How can I do that?

*Additional info:*

I know how to debug Safari for iOS. I just don't have a Mac at the moment.

- Is it true that I need Safari on MacOS X to remote debug Chrome for iOS?
- Does Desktop Chrome allow anything?
- Is Chrome for iOS just a webview application?

Comment: Doubt anything has changed since this was asked: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11262236/ios-remote-debugging

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You cannot directly remote debug Chrome on iOS currently. It uses a uiWebView that may act subtly different than Mobile Safari

You have a few options.

**Option 1: [Remote-debug Mobile Safari using Safari's inspector.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12607124)** If your issue reproduces in Mobile Safari, this is definitely the best way to go. In fact, going through the iOS simulator is even easier.

**Option 2: [Use Weinre for a slimmed down debugging experience](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22047495).**  Weinre doesn't have much features but sometimes it's good enough.

**Option 3: Remote debug a proper uiWebView that functions the same.**

Here's the best way to do this. You'll need to [install XCode](https://developer.apple.com/xcode/downloads/).

1. Go to [github.com/paulirish/iOS-WebView-App](https://github.com/paulirish/iOS-WebView-App) and "Download Zip" or clone.
2. Open XCode, open existing project, and choose the project you just downloaded.
3. Open WebViewAppDelegate.m and change the `urlString` to be the URL you want to test.
4. Run the app in the iOS Simulator.
5. Open Safari, Open the *Develop* Menu, Choose *iOS Simulator* and select your webview.
6. Safari Inspector will now be inspecting your uiWebView.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3):

If you're just looking for the console logs, there's `chrome://inspect`, which will display `console.log` of other tabs in iOS Chrome.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I've had some success with the [iOS remote debug webkit adapter](https://github.com/RemoteDebug/remotedebug-ios-webkit-adapter).

Install [ios-webkit-debug-proxy](https://github.com/google/ios-webkit-debug-proxy#installation) and [libimobiledevice](https://github.com/libimobiledevice/libimobiledevice)

`npm install remotedebug-ios-webkit-adapter -g`

Enable remote debugging in Safari - iOS Settings => Safari preferences => enable "Web Inspector"

Make your computer trust your iOS device- starting iTunes could prompt the "Trust this computer" dialog.

`remotedebug_ios_webkit_adapter --port=9000`

Open tabs should show up in chrome://inspect/#devices
[image: Chrome debuig device inspection]

Answer (score 1):

> Is it true that I need Safari on MacOS X to remote debug Chrome for iOS?

As far as I understand, yes.

> Does Desktop Chrome allow anything?

No

> Is Chrome for iOS just a webview application?

Yes, the app would be rejected otherwise, this is why Mozilla *originally* did not build a browser for iOS.

Answer (score 1):

The Firefox Tools Adaptor allows one to use Firefox DevTools to debug websites on Safari or Google Chrome for iOS or Android.

https://github.com/mozilla/valence#debugging-safari-firefox-and-other-webviews-on-ios