# Webpage breaks on mobile devices (aw, snap!)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a problem with the https://konfiguratorszkolen.pl/ webpage - it works fine on desktop, but breaks on mobile devices.

On mobile, it loads at first and everything looks fine, but after a 1-2sec it shows "aw, snap" error. I've checked it only with Chrome and Safari on iPhone, but I believe it's a general problem.

I've already checked the website on 
https://search.google.com/test/mobile-friendly 
and 
https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/ 
and the result are alright (mobile performance would be better).

What might be the problem? How can I debug this issue on mobile (of course works fine on a desktop browser)?

Here is the repository (it's only a code look-in): https://github.com/KamilSobieraj/Konfigurator_szkolen

Comment: What phone and what mobile browser? Or does it happen on any/all?

Comment: I've checked it only on Chrome and iPhone, but I believe it's a general problem.

Comment: It's not reproduced in devtools device mode

Comment: If it occurs in mobile Safari too you could try remote debugging: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25817651/703903

Answer (score 4):

What you're looking for is called remote debugging and is available for [firefox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Remote_Debugging), [chrome](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/remote-debugging/?hl=en) and there's even solutions to [debug iOS safari from your computer](https://github.com/RemoteDebug/remotedebug-ios-webkit-adapter) (no Mac needed).