# Debugging Chrome on iPhone/iPad

Tags: javascript, iphone, ipad, google-chrome, remote-debugging

How to debug java script code on iPad/iPhone using Google Chrome Browser. How can I do that?

I have tried this **[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11262236/ios-remote-debugging)**. But this work only for *safari browser*.

Comment: I am having this trouble as well, we are seeing a chrome on iOS specific bug but there is no way to debug. Even using Weinre, we can not see console logs...

Comment: I think this is now a duplicate of this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11262236/ios-remote-debugging