# Debugging google chrome on iPhone

Tags: php, google-chrome, oop, debugging, session

I am trying to locate a problem that i cannot see. On my desktop filling an object is working and it is remebered when going to a new page, but when i do the same on my iPhone the session is made and filled but not remembered when i open a new page.

What i have already done is searching the whole internet including stackoverflow for answers that i could not find.

I would like to know how i could open something like developer tools foor google chrome on my iphone. Could someone tell me how I can achieve something like that?

Comment: do you have an mac and do you need chrome?

Comment: @dschniepp i dont have a mac, and i need chrome yes

Comment: Try doing it in SauceLabs?

Comment: This isn't about debugging capabilities, but are you using Safari on the phone?  If you are not, and it is something like a phonegap app, then sessions are not handled in the same way and therefore you need a special solution for managing the session info.

Answer (score 1):

Due to the webkit policies it's [not possible](https://github.com/google/ios-webkit-debug-proxy/issues/16) to debug chrome on iOS because chrome is relaying on the UIWebView.

Its possible for:

Safari (iOS) -> Safari (Mac)
Chrome (Android) -> Safari (Mac/Windows)

More infos: [iOS Remote Debugging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11262236/ios-remote-debugging)