# My website navigation bugging on some iOS devices

Tags: ios, html, css, responsive-design

Today when testing a project of mine, I found out that the mobile navigation of my website isn't show it's list items on some iOS devices.
I tested on Iphone 5 and IPad mini, and those worked,
then i tested on an Iphone 4 and a old Ipad and it didnt show the list items of my navigation. So i think it i enclosed the problem to a outdate iOS or device i guess?
I really have no idea how i should be debugging this problem without being able to use the inspect element tool i have on a desktop. I also don't really find a problem in my code.

My website url is: http://gillesvercammen.be/praniels/
if anyone could be brave enough to test this on an older iOS device, that would be awesome. Below I will put some snippets of relevant code for the bug.
Please forgive me if my code is a little messy, this is my first decent sized project.

This is my full navigation (although the problem only lies in the list items not showing when expanding the hamburger menu)

```
<header>

    <a href="#" title="praniels logo" class="logo">
        <img src="<?=$prefix?>images/logo.svg" alt="logo van praniels">
    </a>

    <nav class="floatfix nav">
        <div id="hamburgerknop"> 
            <a href="#" title="praniels logo" class="mobile-logo">
                <img src="<?=$prefix?>images/logo.svg" alt="logo van praniels">
            </a>
        <span id="hamburger" class="fa fa-bars"></span>
    </div> 
    <ul class="main-nav">
        <li><a class="<?php if(isset($home)){ echo($home); } ?>" href="<?=$prefix?>index.php" title="naar homepage">Home</a></li>
        <li><a class="<?php if(isset($overons)){echo($overons);} ?>" href="<?=$prefix?>over-ons/over-ons.php" title="naar over ons">Over Ons</a></li>
        <li><a class="<?php if(isset($producten)){echo($producten);} ?>" href="<?=$prefix?>producten/producten.php" title="naar producten">Producten</a></li>
        <li><a class="<?php if(isset($workshops)){echo($workshops);} ?>" href="<?=$prefix?>workshops/workshops.php" title="naar workshops pagina">Workshops</a></li>
        <li><a class="<?php if(isset($klanten)){echo($klanten);} ?>" href="<?=$prefix?>klanten/klanten.php" title="naar klantenpagina">Klanten</a></li>
        <li><a class="<?php if(isset($contact)){echo($contact);} ?>" href="<?=$prefix?>contact/contact.php" title="naar contactpagina">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>


    <ul class="icon-nav">
        <li><a href="https://www.facebook.com/" class="icon icon-mono facebook" target="_blank" title="link naar facebook"><span class="fa fa-facebook"></span></a></li>
        <li><a href="https://twitter.com/?lang=nl" class="icon icon-mono twitter" target="_blank" title="link naar twitter"><span class="fa fa-twitter"></span></a></li>
        <li><a href="https://plus.google.com" class="icon icon-mono googleplus" target="_blank" title="link naar google plus"><span class="fa fa-google-plus"></span></a></li>
        <li><a href="https://www.instagram.com/" class="icon icon-mono instagram" target="_blank" title="link naar instagram"><span class="fa fa-instagram" target=_"blank"></span></a></li>
    </ul>
    <?php 
    if(isset($_SESSION["fldEmail"])){
        ?>
        <a href="<?=$prefix?>logout.php" class="logout" title="link naar logout"><span class="fa fa-lock"></span>Logout</a> 
    <?php if(isset($_SESSION["admin"])) { ?>
        <a href="<?=$prefix?>admin/admin.php" class="admingo" tile="link naar adminpagina"><span class="fa fa-lock"></span>Admin</a> 
    <?php } else {}}

    else { ?> <a href="<?=$prefix?>klanten/klanten.php" class="logout" title="link naar logout"><span class="fa fa-unlock-alt"></span>Login</a> <?php }
    ?>

        </nav>
</header>
```

Following are some relevant CSS lines

```
 header { 
  /*background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.5);*/
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  height: 120px;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 10;
  display: block;
}

.logo {
  z-index: 12;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50px;
  top: 0;
  display: block;;
  width: 150px;
  padding-top: 10px;
}

.nav {
  z-index: 11;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}


.non-transparent
{
  z-index: 11;
   background-color: rgb(31,15,16) !important; 
}

.main-nav {

  list-style: none;
}
.mobile-logo {
  display: none;
}
.nav li {

  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  height: 120px;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  text-transform: uppercase;


}

.nav li a {

  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
  -moz-transform: translateY(-50%);
  -o-transform: translateY(-50%);
  transform: translateY(-50%); 
  font-weight: bold;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  line-height: 16px;
  height: 16px;
  padding: 25px 10px 24px;
}

.nav li a:hover {
  color: rgb(212,192,152);
}

.nav ul li .active {
    color: rgb(212,192,152);
    }

.icon-nav {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0px;
    top: 0;
    margin-right: 50px;
}

.icon {
  display: inline-block;
  zoom: 1;
  vertical-align: top;
  width: 44px;
  height: 0;
  padding-top: 44px;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-align: left;
  white-space: nowrap;

}

.logout {
  position: absolute;
  right: 10px;
  top: 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
  border: 1px solid rgb(246,246,226);
  padding: 5px;
}
.admingo {
  position: absolute;
  right: 80px;
  top: 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
  border: 1px solid rgb(246,246,226);
  padding: 5px;
}
.fa-lock, .fa-unlock-alt {
  margin-right: 5px;
}

.logout:hover {
  border: 1px solid rgb(212,192,152);
  color: rgb(212,192,152);
}

/* ================= RWD =============== */




    @media screen and (min-width: 769px) { 
      .logo {display: block !important;  }

      #hamburgerknop { display: none !important; } 
      .nav { display: block !important; } 
    }


         @media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
              header {
            height: 80px;
          }

           .main-nav {
            display: none;
          }
          .expand .main-nav {
            display: block;
          }

          #hamburgerknop {
            background: rgba(31,15,16, 0.35);
            padding: 8px;
            text-decoration: none;
            width: 100%;
            z-index: 2;
            height: 80px;
          }



  #hamburgerknop span {
        margin-top: 15px;
        cursor: pointer;
        display: block;
        padding: 3px 4px 3px;
        position: relative;
        color: rgb(246,246,226);
        font-size: 2em;
        line-height: .8;
        text-align: center;
      }
      .nav ul {
        list-style: none;
        margin: 0;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        background-color:rgb(31,15,16); 
        padding: 0;
      }

      .main-nav {
        height: 0px;
      }

      .nav li:nth-child(1){
        padding-top: 5%;
      }
      .nav li {
        display: block;
        position: relative;
        font-size: 1em;
        font-weight: bold;
        height: 20%;
      }
        .nav li a {
        height: initial;
        display: block ; 
        background: none !important;
        color: #fff;
        text-decoration: none;
      }
      .nav { 
        clear: both;
        position: fixed;
      }


      nav {
        height: auto;
        display: none;
        position: fixed;
      } 
      .expand {
        display: block !important; 
      }
      .logo {
        display: none;
      }

      .mobile-logo {
        z-index: 12;
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        display: block;
        margin-top: 5px;
        width: 100px;
      }
        }
```

Comment: If you still have those older devices, you may try using [WeInRe](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22047495/5108318) to debug your site

Answer (score 0):

Please use below mentioned code:

```
.non-transparent {
    background-color: #1f0f10 !important;
    max-height: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
    z-index: 11;
}
```

**instead**

```
.non-transparent
{
  z-index: 11;
   background-color: rgb(31,15,16) !important; 
}
```