# Arrow functions on Chrome for iOS

Tags: javascript, ios, google-chrome, ecmascript-6, arrow-functions

My `d3.js` graphs are not showing correctly when I access my website with Chrome on my iPhone 6s.

It seems to be because I use ES6 syntax (arrow functions).

But if I check http://caniuse.com/#feat=arrow-functions, it says that Chrome does support arrow functions. The website hasn't listed Chrome for iOS, but should it make a big difference?

If arrow functions are not supported, does it also mean that I cannot use `Array.map()`, `Array.forEach()`, etc?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Chrome for iOS has some pretty major technical restrictions imposed by the App Store, such as the requirement to use the built-in UIWebView for rendering, no V8, and a single-process model. As a result it’s been challenging to re-use critical Chromium infrastructure components. That said, there is a lot of code we do leverage, such as the network layer, the sync and bookmarks infrastructure, omnibox, metrics and crash reporting, and a growing portion of content.

*Source: [https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/chromium-dev/vYGxPx-tVKE](https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/chromium-dev/vYGxPx-tVKE_)*

> But if I check http://caniuse.com/#feat=arrow-functions, it says that Chrome does support arrow functions. The website hasn't listed Chrome for iOS, but should it make a big difference?

So, you might check whether the features you're looking for are supported or not, for `iOS Safari` not for `Chrome`. `Chrome` in `iOS` is not using the same rendering engine as it is in desktop machines.

You better, compile your code before releasing it to production with [babel.js](https://babeljs.io) for example. This way, you can write your code as anyway you like and then deploy it to the platforms with graceful degradation.

> Does it also mean that I cannot use Array.map(), Array.forEach(), etc?

`Array.map`, `Array.forEach` are from `ES5` and `ES5` is widely supported. Just try, I think that they will work.

Comment: Thank you :-) I have changed my arrow functions now, but it still doesn't work with my current code. I have experienced this before where removing the arrow functions solved the problem. But now I have very much code to debug. Do you know a tool to test it? I guess it has some javascript error, but I cannot find a developer tab on my iPhone

Comment: Np:) Here is some tips on how to do that: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11262236/ios-remote-debugging/22047495#22047495