# What would cause Chrome on iPhone load slower/not at all compared with Safari on the same device?

Tags: javascript, ios, iphone, google-chrome, ios10

If I try to do a Google search for "website loading slower in Chrome than in Safari", I get a lot of results about how Safari is slower than Chrome.  However, in a website I'm working on, it loads really well in Safari on my iPhone 6s with iOS 10.2.1 but loads very slowly, hangs, and often doesn't load at all in Chrome on the same device.  The same website loads fine on an iPad Mini 2 with iOS 10.0.2 on Safari and Chrome, and on desktop there are no issues.  Since there is no decent way to debug Chrome on iOS, does anyone know what architectural differences there might be between Chrome on an iPhone and an iPad.  The Chrome versions are exactly the same (57.0.2987.100).  I am using RequireJS, PostalJS, jQuery, Underscore

Comment: There is too a decent way to debug Chrome on iOS: Chrome remote.

Comment: Do you have a link on how to set that up?  I tried to connect Chrome to my iOS device's Chrome and it said that it was connected but I couldn't see the device.  Upon further searches, I only saw that there was no way to debug Chrome on iOS without WeinRe or whatever.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11262236/ios-remote-debugging

Comment: It might require using something like weinre - I'm pretty sure I've done it

Comment: Actually, you're right @Pointy and I tried setting it up but unfortunately I'm using CodeKit 3 and switching everything to grunt/gulp so I can use weinre will be a task in itself.  Besides, I'm interested in any general differences between a WebView based browser and Safari that might be entering the equation.